# Put text before string Jquery

Tags: jquery, text, append

I want add text in a div element that already has a text. I used .append() but this will put the text after the text that already is inside. I want to append the text before the text that already is inside. =)

But how?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add before the existing content.

> **.prepend( content [, content ] )** - Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at `prepend()`

Example:-

```
$('selectorContainer').prepend('Text to appear first or element selector or element itself inside the selectorContainer');
```

See [Doc](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

#### [Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PJfA/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').prepend("something");
```

- http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1):

If the element contains only text, get the text from the element, concatenate it with your text, and put it back. Example:

```
$('#me').text('Prefix' + $('#me').text());
```

If you want to add it as an element, use the `prepend` method:

```
$('#me').prepend('Prefix');
```